# Functions on tensor products

Tags: tensor-products

I am working on tensor products and more importantly showing flatness and this is a question primarily about interpreting what it says in the book.

It shows this
$$A\otimes B_1 \overset{1\otimes f}{\to}A\otimes B_2$$
I just want to make certain I understand it correctly, let
$$a\otimes b\in A\otimes B_1$$
then if I understand it correctly we should have
$$(1\otimes f)(a\otimes b)=1(a)\otimes f(b)$$
am I correct or am I misunderstanding? 1 here being the identity function

Comment: Your understanding is correct, though of course you should remember that not all elements of the tensor product have this form (so you need to extend by linearity).

Comment: yes I am aware of that, I was primarely having notational issues but thank you :)

Comment: Great. You might also want to note that some authors will write $A\otimes f$ rather than $1\otimes f$ (I don't like this notation, but you may as well get used to it).

Comment: I simply have to agree with you there, that one is ugly, id or 1 is much better. But thank you again! If you write a proper answer I'll give it the reward ti deserves :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct.

In general, if $f: A\to B$ and $g: C\to D$ are morphisms then the map $f\otimes g: A\otimes C\to B\otimes D$ is defined to be the unique morphism satisfying $(f\otimes g)(a\otimes b) = f(a)\otimes g(b)$ (uniqueness then follows from the universal property of the tensor product).